"playwright install firefox chromium" gives error "playwright: command not found"
I am trying to run playwright in my Windows WSL2 but it fails.
majeed@DESKTOP-3PJANB1:~/test/test_out$ playwright install firefox chromium
playwright: command not found


By the way, playwright will pre-install firefox, chromium, and webkit, so this isn't really necessary unless you uninstalled them.

Did you install playwright before trying to run it? Usually I run npx playwright commands.

You can install Playwright globally by running the following command in your terminal:
npm install -g playwright


you can install playwright's browsers with command:
 npx playwright install

I recomend for more information, you read my article in medium:
Getting Started with Playwright — Introduction to Web Testing Automation

You can see all the supported browsers by:
npx playwright install --help

and then download a specific browser by:
npx playwright install chrome


Problem: While installing Playwright, the execution policy of the system may sometimes be restricted, preventing successful installation. You might also encounter the following error:
"Cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system."
Solution:
To fix this issue, follow these steps:

Open Windows PowerShell in Administrator mode.
Run the following command to check your current execution policy:
Get-ExecutionPolicy


If it returns "Restricted", you need to change it to "Unrestricted".


Change the execution policy by running this command:
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
After updating the execution policy, try installing Playwright again. The installation should now work as expected.

